# SVG loading vue-svg-loader; [Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

При попытке использования vue-svg-loader получаю:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition: /img/fire.0f28c25a.svg

Проект сделан с использованием vue cli 3, согласно документации лоадера сделал следующее:

установил `npm i -D vue-svg-loader`
 в файл `vue.config.js` добавил запись:

```
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
      const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');

      svgRule.uses.clear();

      svgRule
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader');
    }
```

импортирую файл svg и использую его как компонент:

```
<template>
  <Icon />
</template>
import Icon from '@/assets/img/fire.svg'
export default {
  name: 'app-icon',
  components: {
    Icon
  }
}
```

Пересмотрел много постов на эту тему в том числе и этот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904540/svg-loading-vue-svg-loader-vue-warn-invalid-component-definition Однако добиться нужного результата та и не вышло

UPD: команда vue inspect показывает такое правило для svg:

```
/* config.module.rule('svg') */
      {
        test: /\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [
          /* config.module.rule('svg').use('vue-svg-loader') */
          {
            loader: 'vue-svg-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Вы импортируете `human.svg`, а ругается на `fire.svg`

Comment: @ Рустам Гимранов да это просто разные картинки пробовал, думал мож в картинке проблема. Исправил что-бы не вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: Я стесянюсь спросить: а что, svg-файл можно использовать как компонент?

Comment: @ Дмытрык ну вроде как документация к лоадеру говорит что да....
https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader

Comment: А что говорит `console.log(Icon)` , после его импорта?

Comment: https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/issues/1#issuecomment-268308578 - пишут, что надо удалить `svg` из регулярки

Comment: /img/phone.8890576d.svg - консоль говорит это

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94001/discussion-between-pepel-xd-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл вот такое описание подключения лоадера. В вашем же варианте я не вижу регулярки, по которой вебпак будет искать свгшки. Вот [тут](https://vue-svg-loader.js.org/#npm), если что, видел.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'vue-svg-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Да, но если переключить вкладку на vue cli то там ровно то что и у меня https://vue-svg-loader.js.org/#vue-cli

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема решилась сама собой, точнее лоадер не работал из - за того, что конфиг вебпака во vue cli динамический и собирается во время запуска (npm run serve/npm run build). Я же пробовал изменить конфиг не вырубая девсервера.